# JavaFX: ProgressIndicator in TableCell - icon size in indeterminate mode + label placement

Tags: javafx

I am currently using a progressbar (pb) stacked with a label to show % in a custom cell factory, but I like to implement ProgressIndicator (pi) instead to save on space.

The standard implementation does not render well - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/img/progress-samples.png

1. when pi is in indeterminate mode, the revolving icon gets bigger and the row gets resized - can the size be controlled and make it fit the default row size of the TableView ?
2. pi comes up with a % (and 'Done' when 100%) label but it shows underneath the pi - can it be moved on the right (and vertically aligned) ?

See the code I use today for reference:

```
    progressCln.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<>( "selected" ) ); 
    progressCln.setCellFactory(column -> new TableCell<Segment, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Boolean selected, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(selected, empty);
            Segment seg = (Segment) getTableRow().getItem();
            if (empty || !selected) {
                setGraphic(null);
                setText(null);
                if (seg!=null) seg.setProgress(0);
            } else if (seg != null )  { // for some reasons, seg got null

                StackPane sp = new StackPane();
                Label lb = new Label();
                ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();

                sp.getChildren().addAll(lb, bar);
                bar.progressProperty().unbind();
                bar.progressProperty().bind(seg.progressBarProperty());

                //show % only when uploading
                lb.textProperty().bind(
                        new When (bar.progressProperty().greaterThan(0))
                                .then(bar.progressProperty().multiply(100).asString("%.0f%%"))
                                .otherwise(""));
                lb.setGraphic(bar);
                setGraphic(sp);
                lb.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.CENTER);
                lb.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-font-size: 8pt;");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can force the size by setting the preferred width and heigth:

   final ProgressIndicator indicator = new ProgressIndicator();
   indicator.setPrefSize( 50, 50 );
   That way the indicator keeps the same bounds in both modes.
2. I don't see any other way besides the way you showed. You can access the text inside the indicator using the CSS class `percentage` as documented here [ProgressIndicator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#progressindicator). But that only allows for styling. The layout is managed by the `ProgressIndicatorSkin` class (l.423).

Also consider abstracting your custom progress indicator into its own widget.